# Why my branch is ahead of origin/master after git review?

Tags: git, gerrit, git-commit, git-review

After having my changes submited to gerrit and accepted by a reviewer, git status complains that I'm ahead of origin/master.

Full story:

I've cloned my repo from `ssh://luis@somewhere:10022/project.git`

Because `git review -s` was complaining about a gerrit remote not existing, I did:

```
git remote add gerrit ssh://luis@somewhere:10022/project.git
```

Note that by now, origin and gerrit both point to the same place (I don't know if that's a problem).

I decided not to use a new branch and just work on master.

After my changes were done and staged I did:

```
git commit
git review
```

At this point git status says that I'm ahead of origin/master by 1 commit, which is odd because I thought that git review had an implicit push.

The changes were reviewed and accepted in the gerrit web-interface and have been merged into origin/master (everyone else can see them), but my local repo still says I'm ahead.

I tried pulling from origin but that triggered a merge, and now I'm 2 commits ahead.

Is this normal? Should I simply discard my extra local changes? Push them to origin?

Thanks,

Luis

Answer (score 1):

Usually, I am able to resolve this by running

```
git pull
```

This happens because the index for git sometimes does not get updated, and has nothing to do with the `git review`.

Check accepted answer for ['Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit' on explicit push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050978/your-branch-is-ahead-of-origin-master-by-1-commit-on-explicit-push)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. git pull, git pull origin master,git pull gerrit master. None of them has effect, it always says Already up-to-date.
git push, as suggested by the command line, fails because direct pushes to origin are forbidden by gerrit.

Comment: @Luis I am assuming `git fetch` also does not help?

Comment: git pull == git fetch and git merge

Comment: I had the same problem and git pull solved it. I now Get "Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'."

Answer (score 1):

git review will not push your change to the master but submits a patch-set for review. This means that you local branch is indeed ahead of the master unless your patch-set has been merged with your branch. For details of which branch is being targeted you need to check your .gitreview file in the root of your project.