# uploading files to git as a group

Tags: git, uploading

a group project has been set up on get with two other people, the first person has cloned the repository and is able to upload files. When myself and the second person try to upload any files we get the following message, why is this and how do we fix it?

Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit' on explicit push](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050978/your-branch-is-ahead-of-origin-master-by-1-commit-on-explicit-push)

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean by "upload files". Git does not upload files (nor push them, for that matter): Git operates on *commits*. When you run `git push` you are telling your Git to call up the Git on `origin`, hand over any new commits you have that they don't, and then asking them to set *their* `master` to your newest `master` commit. When you run `git fetch` you get your Git to call up their Git, bring over their commits, and update *your* `origin/master` to remember *their* `master`.

Comment: I have no idea what you said as I'm new to git

Comment: You'd best read some beginner documentation on Git, then. The Pro Git book at https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2 is free, and pretty good.